# Do we need to be [changed]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, meta-tags

[changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/changed) currently has 32 questions.

It doesn't have a specific meaning, it's not helpful to the questions. Request to burninate the tag.

Comment: I like that some of them seem to be trying to spell a sentence with the tags, like "android orientation changed" and "gdb char const changed". It's like an even more restrictive form of poetry than haiku.

Comment: Given the relatively small volume of tagged questions, one person could pretty reasonably edit out the tag and and improve / close vote those questions.

Comment: @jdphenix Good point. I'll work on that.

Comment: @jdphenix Nonetheless, it's good to ask. I've seen a debacle or two come from not posting a [tag:burninate-request] first.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Given the small volume of questions that jdphenix pointed out, I went ahead and edited all the good questions and flagged all of the bad.

I tried to improve as much as I could while removing the tag; there shouldn't be any more soon! The tag should indeed be burninated. No question that I edited needed it.

I think we can safely assume that [changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/changed) should be...
[image: BURNINATED]

Comment: [What!! Burninated and no Image? ಠ_ಠ](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Zm85C.png)

Comment: Life is not complete until I go home and add that image to my answer.