# We don't want [changes]!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I thought we agreed that [we don't need to be [changed]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293590/do-we-need-to-be-changed), but it turns out that there are [changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/changes) taking place already.

There are only 45 questions under [changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/changes) in a wide range of areas. I haven't seen any sign that this tag having any particular meaning in the questions. Let's burninate it.

Comment: Well first we'll have to remove that question which has been locked due to being merged, otherwise cleaning up the others won't do much.

Comment: did a handful. @Quant: There's a stronger case for a mod to handle that merge-stub when it's all that's left.

Comment: No, don't [tag:change] anything! Err... wait...

Comment: Done.. apart from the two I can't change. One has a pending edit and I've done my edits today. The other is a duplicate and can't be edited.

Comment: I have flagged the uneditable question for a moderator's intervention.

Comment: Wait, can I add a [[Ch-ch-Changes](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/davidbowie/changes.html)] synonym before we burniate it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/changes) have stopped.  They should vanish entirely within the next 24 hours.

Comment: The locked merge-stub is still there, so no vanishing. Though I flagged it for mod-attention, "*Locked merge-stub is blocking burnination of [changes]: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300971 Please delete or replace tag with [file-monitoring].*", which should help.

Comment: Damn, I have to get used to the new navigation not showing everything when I'm on the wrong tab.

Comment: Well, that was fast turn-around on the flag...